# index of large numbers in array

Tags: python, list

Given an array of numbers, what would be a quick way in Python to return the Indices of top 1/3 percent largest numbers in this array?

for example, [4,8,2,7,6,3], return [1, 3] (indices for 8 and 7)

Thanks,

Comment: Yes there is. But how did you try it and where did that attempt go wrong?

Comment: Sort the array descending and take as many of the highest numbers from the beginning of the array as you want.

Comment: If you still need the resulting indices from the original array, use the result of my description above to search the original array, using a nested loop.

Comment: `[x.index(num) for num in sorted(x, reverse=True)[:len(x)//3]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just care of implementing quickly and not about efficiency:

```
a = [4, 8, 2, 7, 6, 3]
b = [(i, j) for i, j in enumerate(a)]
c = sorted(b, key=lambda x: x[1])
d = [x[0] for x in c[-(len(c) // 3):]]
```

d will contain: `[3, 1]`

Answer (score 2):

You could turn the list into a list of `(element, index)` tuples, then use [`heapq.nlargest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest). Then we can select the index from the result list using a list comprehension.

```
>>> from heapq import nlargest
>>> lst = [4,8,2,7,6,3]
>>> n = len(lst) // 3
>>> idx = [(e, i) for i, e in enumerate(lst)]
>>> [i for _, i in nlargest(n, idx)]
[1, 3]
```

From the docs for `heapq.nlargest`:

> Return a list with the n largest elements from the dataset defined by iterable. key, if provided, specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each element in iterable (for example, key=str.lower). Equivalent to: sorted(iterable, key=key, reverse=True)[:n].

Answer (score 0):

A straight forward way would be

```
l1 = [4,8,2,7,6,3]
elts = sorted(l1, reverse=True)[0:int(len(l1)/3)]
idcs = [l1.index(e) for e in elts]
print(idcs)
```